# Crash running app build on macOS 13.6 (clang 15), when running on macOS 11 (dynamic_cast)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, objective-c++, abi

Have an issue that started when I upgraded xcode to 15 on a build server.

Apps that are linking against binaries build "some time ago" (tm) - now crash when run on macOS11 or earlier. The same binary runs fine on on macos12/13/14.

The culprit is any dynamic_cast, a simplified example is shown below (minimal single file app that has same fault):

OS target is: 10.14
c++ dialect is: C++11 (-std=c++11 ... same as the old libraries I'm linking against)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <osg/AnimationPath>
#import <osg/ref_ptr>

/*
 Define some subclass of osg::AnimationPath, so we have something to downcast to
 */
class PanZoomAnimationPath : public osg::AnimationPath {
public:
    PanZoomAnimationPath() {
        setLoopMode(osg::AnimationPath::NO_LOOPING);
    }
};


@interface AppDelegate () {
    osg::ref_ptr<osg::AnimationPath>  _animationPath;
}

@property (strong) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Try to do some dynamic cast
    
//    auto createdPath = new osg::AnimationPath();
    auto createdPath = new PanZoomAnimationPath();
    
    // shove into a ref_ptr that is on the class
    _animationPath = createdPath;

    NSLog(@"Ptr to path: %p", createdPath);
    NSLog(@"Ptr from _animationPath: %p", _animationPath.get());
    NSLog(@"Animation path ptr is: %p. Is it valid: %d", _animationPath.get(), _animationPath.valid());
    
    // try to dynamic cast. BOOM (at least, on macOS 11)
    PanZoomAnimationPath *pStudioPath = dynamic_cast<PanZoomAnimationPath * >(_animationPath.get());
    if(pStudioPath) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"createdPath is not of type PanZoomAnimationPath");
    }
}

@end
```

When run on macOS13/14, this works and produces the right output, correctly downcasting and either being NULL or not depending on the pointer.

On macOS11 if fails (segfault 11)

Here's the stack trace:

```
Path:                  /Users/USER/TestOld.app/Contents/MacOS/TestOld
Identifier:            com.shinywhitebox.TestOld
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        bash [62750]
User ID:               504

Date/Time:             2023-09-28 20:50:19.100 +1300
OS Version:            macOS 11.7.8 (20G1351)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        86319E29-4169-27B2-C19A-1C7378984637

Sleep/Wake UUID:       D03F977E-2B4B-443D-8EB9-8478E632ECBD

Time Awake Since Boot: 790000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       1500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000007e6b008
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [63209]

VM Regions Near 0x7e6b008:
--> 
    __TEXT                      107e6b000-107e73000    [   32K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Users/*/TestOld.app/Contents/MacOS/TestOld

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff20543d16 __dynamic_cast + 393
1   com.shinywhitebox.TestOld       0x0000000107e6ea2f -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] + 255
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2066d463 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20708ed9 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke + 49
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20708e54 _CFXRegistrationPost + 496
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff2063e6ce _CFXNotificationPost + 736
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff213b1c18 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 59
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e88d80 -[NSApplication _postDidFinishNotification] + 305
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e88ad2 -[NSApplication _sendFinishLaunchingNotification] + 208
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e85c71 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleAEOpenEvent:] + 541
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e858c7 -[NSApplication(NSAppleEventHandling) _handleCoreEvent:withReplyEvent:] + 665
11  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff213dd366 -[NSAppleEventManager dispatchRawAppleEvent:withRawReply:handlerRefCon:] + 308
12  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff213dd1d6 _NSAppleEventManagerGenericHandler + 80
13  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff2645b853 0x7fff2644f000 + 51283
14  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff2645af6e 0x7fff2644f000 + 49006
15  com.apple.AE                    0x00007fff26453cd3 aeProcessAppleEvent + 448
16  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff288d3012 AEProcessAppleEvent + 54
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e7ff70 _DPSNextEvent + 2046
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e7e2a5 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1364
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e705c9 -[NSApplication run] + 586
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff22e447cc NSApplicationMain + 816
21  com.shinywhitebox.TestOld       0x0000000107e6e81f main + 47
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff2059af3d start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.CFVolumeObserver.0x7fad90e1fe60
```

When run from macOS 14, you get:

```
Ptr from _animationPath: 0x60000039a7d0
Animation path ptr is: 0x60000039a7d0. Is it valid: 1
Success!
```

From macOS11:

```
2023-09-28 21:10:10.997 TestOld[63675:8470300] Ptr from _animationPath: 0x7fe879e2c3b0
2023-09-28 21:10:10.997 TestOld[63675:8470300] Animation path ptr is: 0x7fe879e2c3b0. Is it valid: 1
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I've tried recompiling the old libraries as well, and this hasn't worked.  It crashes on different dynamic_casts.

I'm no expert at ABI related issues, so asking for any help / pointers here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a change in the linker in Xcode 15. It's [documented in the release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#Linking) but it's easy to miss and not easy to find if you don't know where to look. You'd think they'd add a build-time warning when your project contains affected symbols and targets older macOS versions…

Anyway, the release notes also document a work-around:

> Binaries using symbols with a weak definition crash at runtime on iOS 14/macOS 12 or older. This impacts primarily C++ projects due to their extensive use of weak symbols. (114813650) (FB13097713)
>
> **Workaround:** Bump the minimum deployment target to iOS 15, macOS 12, watchOS 8 or tvOS 15, or **add `-Wl,-ld_classic` to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting.**

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Wow. Thank you. This works on my test project (using -ld_classic 'other linker flags'). I'll go see if it works on the real thing. There's no *way* I would have found this myself. Thanks!